# Keep checkboxes checked after refresh within a Twig template- PHP

Tags: php, checkbox, filter

I am attempting to create a search functionality that allows for filtering of results in such a way that reloads the page with new results each time you click an option on the clickbox, but also allows you to keep filtering using checkboxes that REMAIN CHECKED after reload.

I have seen a solution for HTML that is something like:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="txtCheck" value="your value" <?php if(isset($_POST['txtCheck'])) echo "checked='checked'"; ?>  /><br />
```

But this does not work in twig. Does anyone know the solution for this within the twig template?

Thank you in advance.

A part of my form is below:

```
<form action="{{ path ('person_search') }}" method="GET">
                <input type="checkbox" name="role" value="Applicant" onclick="this.form.submit()">Applicant<br>
```

Comment: I think you'll need to look into using some kind of persistence such has using `$_COOKIE` or `$_SESSION` and using either PHP in the backend to keep it checked or javascript in the front end.

The code snippet that you've found is exactly what you'd need however the `$_POST` global array is new on every page. Using `$_SESSION` will last until the user closes their browser which is what I think you want, and you can update it when their preferences change. Using `$_COOKIE` can last longer but the user can possibly tamper with the data. Just something to be aware of.

Comment: Reading values from either $_COOKIE or $_SESSION I would create new variables passed by your controller into your template and using if/else logic to mark each checkbox as checked/unchecked.

Comment: Thanks Newbi! I'm a bit of a newcomer to PHP (been riding Rails for my whole experience); do you think you might be able to provide me with some example of how that might look? Much obliged.

Comment: Are you using a specific framework or just pure PHP with Twig? I'm also trying to create a discussion just between you and I but I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: Lets [discuss in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47976/dicussion-between-user3298174-and-newbi3)

Comment: Tried to join, not enough reputation points apparently. PHP/Symfony

Comment: Read up on Cookies and Sessions in Symfony. [Symfony2 HTTP](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/introduction.html) I'm currently working on a Symfony2 project myself and can provide a snippet of a controller I've worked on in a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
PHP
<?php
    use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
    use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

    public function myControllerAction(){
        $isChecked1 = false;
        $isChecked2 = false;

        $request = $this->get('request');
        $cookies = $request->cookies;

        if ($cookies->has('CHECKBOX_1_CHECKED'))
        {
            $isChecked1 = true;
        }

        if ($cookies->has('CHECKBOX_2_CHECKED'))
        {
            $isChecked2 = true;
        }

    return $this->render(
        'MyBundle:Bundle:some.html.twig',
        array(
            'isChecked1' => $isChecked1,
            'isChecked2' => $isChecked2,
        )
    );
}
?>

 TWIG
 <form action="{{ path ('person_search') }}" method="GET">
            <input type="checkbox" name="role1" {%if isChecked1 %} checked="checked" {& endif %} value="Applicant" onclick="this.form.submit()">Applicant<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="role2" {%if isChecked2 %} checked="checked" {& endif %} value="Manager" onclick="this.form.submit()">Manager<br>
```

...
     NOTE
     You can set the cookie with either PHP or using Javascript